# Variable after -= properties

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I insert a variable after -= properties in animate jQuery?

```
var slideObject = $('.object').width();

$('.next').on('click', function(){
    event.preventDefault();

    //See -=slideObject
    $(slideContainer).animate({ marginLeft: -=slideObject}, 500);
});
```

Error in console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token -=

Comment: Yes, that's not valid syntax.

Comment: it's supposed to be a string, so, generate a string.

Comment: ^ `'-=' + slideObject` ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#String_operators

Comment: Put quotes around `"-="`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using your event properly:

```
$('.next').on('click', function( event ){ // << pass as argument
```

also you should use `"-="+ variable`

```
var slideObject = $('.object').width();

$('.next').on('click', function( event ){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(slideContainer).animate({ marginLeft: "-="+ slideObject}, 500);
});
```

Look at the argument we pass to the `.animate()` method as an **Object Literal**:

```
var obj = {
   marginLeft   : 200,       // Valid  (Number)
   marginRight  : "100",     // Valid  (String)
   marginTop    : topValue,  // Valid  (Variable)
   marginBottom : "100px"    // Valid  (String)
}
```

<sub>(Yes exactly, you can use the above as `$(slideContainer).animate(obj, 500);` )</sub>

where in this example:

```
var obj = {
   marginLeft   : -=200,     // Unexpected Token Error
   marginRight  : "-=100"    // Valid  (String)
}
```

So jQuery usually expects is a valid Object. Usually a string value like `"200px"`
To make our lives easier it allows us to use a Number value like: `200` which will be than converted internally to String using `px` as default: `"200px"`.
It allows us to pass inside the Animate object a variable like `{marginLeft : margVal}` but `-=margVal` is no longer a valid object property value but *Unexpected token -=*. If you convert it to String concatenating your Operator with your Variable, jQuery  will than see `"-=200"` a valid string.

Note also that if your `slideContainer` is already a jQuery object, there's no need to wrap it again into jQuery `$()`.